# Additional operations in getter and setter

Tags: c#

Can I freely add additional operations in C# public property's getter and setter? To what extent? 
For example, would the following piece of code be okay (returning and editing a collection which is nested into another collection)?

```
public ObservableCollection<MyEntity> MyCollection
{
   get
   {
     return myColl.Where(p => p.Name == myName).FirstOrDefault().AnotherCollection;
   }
   private set
   {
     myColl.Where(p => p.Name == myName).FirstOrDefault().AnotherCollection = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: *Okay* based on what rule? General coding guidelines? Common sense? Compilable?

Comment: It's compilable, I know it. So, based on general coding guidelines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only bound is the semantics. You may use whatever operations you find suitable, as long as the general property semantics is preserved. Among others, I would check that

- access is reasonably fast
- if setter finished w/o error, getter should return the value semantically compatible with the set value
- if possible, avoid raising exceptions inside
- consecutive gets return semantically equivalent values if internal state didn't change

If you keep the semantics, IMHO any operation is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Realistically, you are allowed to add most anything you want within a propeties getter and setter.  Effectively they are not much more than a easy way to avoid writting this:

```
private String _value;
public String GetValue
{
    return _value;
}
public void SetValue(string value)
{
    _value = value;
}
```

So if you can do it in a method, you *can* do it in a property (doesn't necessarily mean that you should)

As for what is proper, a lot of that depends on context and many people have differing opinions.  The general guidelines I try to follow myself are:

1. Do not do anything that takes too much time.  Properties are expected to be fast.
2. Do not put anything that will throw an `Exception` unless it is documented and it makes sense.   I will use `ArgumentException` or `NullReferenceException` in cases where I have to account for values in the property that will break the code, but otherwise if it needs an exception or I call a method that could result in an exception unrelated to the property itself, then method is better.
3. Use common sense.  If you can say to yourself, I want to `get` or `set` a value, then a property makes sense.  If I want to `do something`, then you are probably better off with a method.
4. This goes back to #1, but if there is no backing field to get or set (automatic properties do this in the background anyways), then you have to think about if a property is really the correct approach.

But as I said, these are my guidelines and I do break them from time to time, but when I do, I tend to make sure it is documented that the property is going to do something unexcepted, or long running.

Your example could throw exceptions if `myColl` or `p` are `null`, so unless you will be 100% certain neither could ever possibly be null, then I would not make this a property.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two rules:

1. Common sense - if you think it shouldn't be like that. Then it probably shouldn't be like that.
2. Principle of least surprise

Answer (score 1):

The code you have provided has a "bad code" smell.

1. You have used FirstOrDefault functions; which may have null values.
2. myName variable seems to be a class level variable. Then in a property you seem to be using more than one class level variable (myColl and myName); which seems a bit strange for me.

   3.You seem to be returning a deep object, `AnotherCollection` which is a property of the first item in a list. This may lead to problems; what if;

a. `myColl` is null,

b. `myValue` is null,

c. `FirstOrDefault` returns null,

d. `AnotherCollection` is null.

Answer (score 0):

it's ok in my opinion,

> some will say it's ugly, some will say it's valid or just ok, maybe
>   nice ...
>
> get/set are in depth 2 methods like get() and set()

*what are the 'general' coding guidlines ?*